# Out of Memory Exception When Creating BACPAC File

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We're having a frustrating time migrating our on-premises SQL application to Azure. The database is large but not crazy, about 265 GB. SQL Server Management Studio > "Deploy Database to Windows Azure SQL Database" will run for 15 - 20 hours, and then fail with a Out of Memory exception when exporting one of our larger tables.

We have BAK files of our database and data. Is there a way to import this into Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Have you considered talking to Microsoft Azure support about this?

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use .back failes in Azure SQL Database (not Managed Instance). I'd sugesst that you should consider to use BCP which is export to local csv or binary files and can import there to Azure SQL Database.